# Get Movie Detail used TMDB API with spesific order

Tags: php, api, movie, imdb

I'm trying to get some movie detail with TMDB API. Then, used this code :

```
<?php

$cs = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/".$id_movie."/credits?api_key=" . $apikey);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json"));
$response9 = curl_exec($cs);
curl_close($cs);
$movie_credits_id = json_decode($response9);
?>
```

To call I use this code :

```
    <?php
    foreach($movie_credits_id->cast as $cst){
    echo $cst->name . ', ';
    }
    ?>
```

It's successfully to get all cast data, but I want to more specific and more simple code to call. So, i try to use this code :

```
<?php foreach($movie_credits_id->cast as $cast); ?>

<?php echo $cast->name ; ?> <br>
```

With that code, I got one actor name that is on the last list of their database that even I didn't know who is he. For this case, I want to know how to get the actor name that in the first list (order : 0) and I want to use more simple code to call like :

```
<?php echo actor ; ?>
```

I hope you can help me because I have no idea with coding.. hehe
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood correctly but you have the foreach and you can use whatever variable names you want in there and you can loop whatever level you want.

```
<?php foreach($movie_credits_id->cast->name as $actor); ?>

<?php echo $actor ; ?> <br>
```

I added `->name` in the declaration and changed the variable to $actor.

However I think a better solution may be to skip the loop and implode the actors.

```
Echo implode("<br>", $movie_credits_id->cast->name);
```

This should echo all actors with a `<br>` tag in-between.